# how to unfolding a box with 8 Sides with CSS3 accurate?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Since a week I try to open a box with html5 css3 and some javascript. 
The final result should be in the first step (button1) "open the box" (like a package) the second should be the "unfolding effect".
It work almost close in this example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Rases/wprt40nr/

```
<div id="cube">
    <figure class="front">Cover</figure>
    <figure class="top">TOP!</figure>
    <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    <figure class="right">R1</figure>
    <figure class="right2">R2</figure>
    <figure class="left">Left1</figure>
    <figure class="left2">Left2</figure>
    <figure class="bottom">Bottom</figure>
</div>
```

but as i learned some parts are not really connected. That's the reason why it's overlap to the step3

So I connected the parts in each other and replace the figure with div tags as you see here.: http://jsfiddle.net/Rases/71gy2qu9/

```
<div id="cube">
    <div class="top">TOP! <div class="front">Cover</div></div>
    <div class="back">back </div>
    <div class="right">Right1 <div class="right2">Right2</div></div>
    <div class="left">left1 <div class="left2">Left2</div></div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom </div>
</div>
```

But this one didn't worked very well and I googled about the diffrent between div and figure and find out the coordinate System woks diffrent
My next idea was to replace the div-tags with the span-tag, because i saw it in section 6: http://rupl.github.io/unfold/

```
<div class="sandbox">
  <div class="cube rotate labels">
   <span class="top side"></span>
   <span class="left side"></span>
   <span class="right side"></span>
   <span class="bottom side"><span class="back side flat"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you can see the folding effect in the second part of section 6
so I try this version: http://jsfiddle.net/Rases/1b6a87t0/

```
 <div class="box" >
  <div id="cube">
    <span class="top">TOP!<span class="front">Front</span></span>
    <span class="back">BACK</span>
    <span class="right">Right1<span class="right2">Right2</span></span>
    <span class="left">Left1<span class="left2">L2</span></span>
    <span class="bottom">Bottom</span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

In the last version of the box is connected but the unfolding effect from step1 to step2 looks wacky. I can't find the mistake and the css have diffrent coordinates the rest ( box and cube is the same )

here is the CSS - Code from my last example

/******* cube-Style *******/

```
.box {
  width: 248px;
  height: 234px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
     -moz-perspective: 1000px;
       -o-perspective: 1000px;
          perspective: 1000px;
}

#cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(-116px);
     -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(-116px);
       -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(-116px);
          transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(-116px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 3s;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 3s;
          transition: transform 3s;
}

#cube span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Update: today I tryed http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/ on the first example but it don't work because the one end move in a circle and the other hand move in a line

The problem on the first example is still, that the Layers are not connected very well:
[image: Moving animation from side of the cube]

So I have to work with the other examples but in this case there is a error for the first open effect. (open the box)
Just Remember: Step one open the box, Step two flat the box.

I can't find the bug... thanks for your support.

Comment: Which version do you want help with?

Comment: Hi, for me it doesn't matter whitch version. The effect has to be working. I didn't know why the last 2 version run in the "frame" of on side an not in a seperate one. as you see in the example of http://rupl.github.io/unfold/ here is also ine section in one other and it works. So in my mind the secound version should work. But it didn't

Comment: Here you can see the example with a cubic-bezier.
http://jsfiddle.net/Rases/wprt40nr/1/
AS you see it never looks conected

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your second example from http://rupl.github.io/unfold/ and added more sides + 2 buttons to control the single steps:

http://jsfiddle.net/uu98t6en/

All you have to do now is to adjust the flat classes to the point where you want to start and do an animation by defining "step"-Classes or just one-by-one.

```
$(".buttton1").click(function()
{
    $(".step1").addClass("flat");
}); 

$(".buttton2").click(function()
{
    $(".step2").addClass("flat");
});

$(".reset").click(function()
{
    $(".step1, .step2").removeClass("flat");
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uu98t6en/2/

I hope this was helpful.

-moritz